# Does WAF need to be included as part of Application Gateway creation?

Tags: powershell, azure-application-gateway

As part of BCP/Disaster Recover planning, we want to simulate a restoration scenario of the application gateway template we have in bitbucket.

I have the json template as well as parameters file in the repository, but I also see a WAF rule template files for the gateway.

So basically there are 4 files....but the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` only takes in the main template file (`-TemplateUri`) as well as parameters file (`-TemplateParameterUri`). so how would i be able to specify the WAF templates as part of the gateway creation?
I do see references to the WAF rules in the main gateway template file but is that enough?

sku information:

```
 "properties": {
 "sku": {
 "name": "WAF_v2",
 "tier": "WAF_v2",
 "capacity": 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ***add WAF policies while creating the WAF v2 Gateway*** by just adding the below in the Template file in the same way it has been done in this [***`Microsoft Documentation`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/quick-create-template#review-the-template) and providing the values as per your requirement :

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('AGWafPol01')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "customRules": [
          {
            "name": "CustRule01",
            "priority": 100,
            "ruleType": "MatchRule",
            "action": "Block",
            "matchConditions": [
              {
                "matchVariables": [
                  {
                    "variableName": "RemoteAddr"
                  }
                ],
                "operator": "IPMatch",
                "negationConditon": true,
                "matchValues": [
                  "10.10.10.0/24"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "policySettings": {
          "requestBodyCheck": true,
          "maxRequestBodySizeInKb": 128,
          "fileUploadLimitInMb": 100,
          "state": "Enabled",
          "mode": "Prevention"
        },
        "managedRules": {
          "managedRuleSets": [
            {
              "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
              "ruleSetVersion": "3.1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```